# Ввод в input только английских буков от A до Z и цифры от 0 до 9

Tags: preg_match, php

Всем привет, я хочу ограничить ввод данных в `<input type = "text" />` только тех символов, что в названии темы. Как это сделать? Я читал, что есть `preg_match`, но я прочитал про него, и посмотрел видео, не могу в нём разобраться. Подскажите, как с ним работать. Сразу говорю о нём на сайте http://php.su я читал, но тоже не понял :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Видимо плохо читали)))
Пример:

```
$text = 'test';

if(!preg_match('|^[A-Z0-9]+$|i', $text))
{
    echo 'В тексте есть недопустимые символы';
}
else
{
    echo 'В тексте только символы латинского алфавита и цифры';
}
```

В примере сложной, на первый взгляд, может показаться только регулярка '|^[A-Z0-9]+$|i'

Поясняю
**^** Означает искать с начала строки

**$** Означает искать вплоть до конца строки

**[A-Z0-9]+** Искать в диапазонах от A до Z и от 0 до 9 плюс значит что пустая строка не пройдет, если пустая строка нормально плюс можно поменять на звездочку *

**i** Модификатор, говоряший регулярке не обращать внимание на регистр символов

Comment: 0_O регулярка сложновата...Но спасибо теперь я понял :)